# kendo ui angular issue connected listboxes with custom actions

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, listbox

I have a issue with the Angular Kendo UI Listbox from Telerik.
I have 2 connected listboxes with the toolbar and custom actions however, they act strange.
When trying to move 1 item down it moves the item 2 times down.
Should I create 2 different viewchilds?

Please see my example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-piaaqm

Thank you,

Comment: Without the complex logic it seems to work fine? what is the actual solution you are trying to achieve? [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-piaaqm-emoye3)

Comment: The logic is not that complex. it is from an official kendo-ui example
https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/listbox/data-binding/
I would like to post someting to an api in order to store it in a database

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to extract the latest values, directly from the listbox and trigger the post API call.

```
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
import { ActionName, ListBoxComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-listbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  {{data}}
        <kendo-listbox
            #Listbox1
            [data]="data"
            (actionClick)="handleActionClick($event)"
            kendoListBoxDataBinding
            [connectedWith]="Listbox2"
            
        >
        </kendo-listbox>
        {{data1}}
        <kendo-listbox
            #Listbox2
            [data]="data1"
            (actionClick)="handleActionClick($event)"
            [toolbar]="false"
            
        >
        </kendo-listbox>
    `,
  styles: [
    `
        kendo-listbox {
            height: 270px;
            width: 240px;
        }
    `,
  ],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public data: string[] = ['Albania', 'Andorra', 'Armenia'];
  public data1: string[] = ['Belgium', 'Luxembourg', 'France'];

  @ViewChildren(ListBoxComponent)
  private listbox: QueryList<ListBoxComponent>;

  public handleActionClick(event: ActionName): void {
    console.log(this.listbox);
    let data = [],
      data1 = [];
    if (this.listbox && this.listbox.length) {
      this.listbox.forEach((item: ListBoxComponent, index: number) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          data = item.data;
        } else {
          data1 = item.data;
        }
      });
      console.log(data, data1);

      // trigger post call here
    }
  }
}
```

If needed also use the event [`selectionChange`](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/listbox/api/ListBoxComponent/#toc-selectionchange) while calling the same function!

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-piaaqm-ysblkk)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in this way I would need to post both the arrays. Wouldn't it be better (from a developpers point of view) to only send the changed item?

Comment: @Maniac_1979 All the best, this is the best I can help you!